# how to use awk for extract a column with a determinate range

Tags: bash, awk

i have a file like this:

> 57580.87499999965802999   -2.01319509921268036e+00>
>
> 57580.91666666632227134   -2.00037110698185661e+00>
>
> 57580.95833333298651269    -1.98754711475190549e+00>
>
> 57580.99999999965075403    -1.97472312252219151e+00>
>
> 57581.04166666631499538    -1.95440667936783941e+00>
>
> 57581.08333333297923673    -1.94158268713747040e+00>
>
> 57581.12499999964347808    -1.92875869490721019e+00>
>
> 57581.16666666630771942    -1.91593470267662269e+00>
>
> 57581.20833333297196077    -1.89561825952250729e+00>

and i would like to use awk to print only the columns that start wit 57581

the code i wrote is

```
DATA=57581
DATA2=57582

awk '{ if ($1 >= $DATA'.00000000000000000' && $1 < $DATA2'.00000000000000000') print $1, $2 >> "file.txt"}' $filename
```

any idea?

thank you

Comment: can you add expected output for clarity? is this what you need? `grep '^57581\.' file`

Comment: Could you please let us know if you want start with or a range of data to be compared by taking shell variables in awk?

Comment: You have 2 contradictory requirements in your question: 1) select records that start with `57581` and 2) select records that lie between the values `57581` and `57582`. Those are 2 very different requirements - [edit] your question to clearly state what the one thing is you really want to do and provide concise, testable sample input and expected output that covers all your use cases (really **think** about edge cases, etc. - don't just throw up a few lines of text that covers 1 sunny day case).

Answer (score 1):

This will do for you:

`awk '/^57581/' file`

```
-bash-4.2$ awk '/^57581/' file
57581.04166666631499538 -1.95440667936783941e+00>
57581.08333333297923673 -1.94158268713747040e+00>
57581.12499999964347808 -1.92875869490721019e+00>
57581.16666666630771942 -1.91593470267662269e+00>
57581.20833333297196077 -1.89561825952250729e+00>
-bash-4.2$
```

> Awk pattern /^57581/ will search at the begining of the line, and the
>   number you where looking for.

The, awk as usual will do the rest, because if the pattern is true, it will print the whole line.

**EDIT**
As suggested by @EdMorton, the OP says to print just the columns starting with 57581, then, the code for this should be:

```
 -bash-4.2$ awk '{for (a=1; a<NF; a++) { if (match($a, '/^57581/')==1){print $a}}}' file
57581.04166666631499538
57581.08333333297923673
57581.12499999964347808
57581.16666666630771942
57581.20833333297196077
-bash-4.2$
```

**EDIT 2**

As suggested, I added the code with a var loaded from Shell:

```
-bash-4.2$ export VAR=57581
-bash-4.2$  awk -v"myvar=$VAR" '{ for (a=1; a<NF; a++) { 
regex="^"myvar""; if ($a ~  regex){print $a}}}' file
57581.04166666631499538
57581.08333333297923673
57581.12499999964347808
57581.16666666630771942
57581.20833333297196077
-bash-4.2$
```

Comment: While what you say is true, it doesn't address the OPs question. If you're not sure why I say that then you should delete this for now until the OP provides the expected output and then her requirements will be clearer.

Comment: The columns.... O_o...I was thinking in rows.... could maybe the user mean rows according to the file structure??? hummm...he prints the two columns `print $1, $2` then I just supposed he wanted the whole row!

Comment: I suggest `awk -F . '$1==57581' file`

Comment: this would only match if column is the first. Check answer!! ;) Thnks @Ed Morton

Comment: My point was actually that the OPs question seems to be about how to pass in 2 variables and select records that fall between the range delimited by those 2 variables, not about how to select records based on one hard-coded value. The example in the question currently is IMHO very misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is

```
awk 'int($1)==57581' file
```

regex checks will give you false positives if not checked for decimal point in the right place (eg. 575810000 will satisfy "starting with" condition).

In your notation, this is equivalent to

```
awk -v lowerInc=57581 -v upperExc=57582 'lowerInc<=$1 && $1<upperExc' file
```